# Applying date format in pandas not working as expected?

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying out pandas library to process lot of excel files which have same columns.

Here is my function;

```
def read_dipsfile(writer):
    atg_path = '/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/DataLoader/data/dips'
    files = os.listdir(atg_path)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    dateCol = ['Dip Time']
    for f in files:
        if(f.endswith('.CSV')):
            data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(atg_path, f), delimiter=',', skiprows=[1], skipinitialspace=True,
                               parse_dates=dateCol)

            data['Dip Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Dip Time'])

            if mid_day_check(data['Dip Time']):
                data['Dip Time'] = data['Dip Time'].dt.normalize()
                data['Dip Time'] = data['Dip Time'] .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                df = df.append(data)

    x = df.groupby(['Dip Time','Site', 'Tank ID','Product','Volume'], as_index=False).apply(atg_aggregation)
    x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DipsSummary')
```

Here I expect my Dip Time column will show dates as '01-09-2019' (date-month-year)
But I get finally  (month-date -year format ) 09/01/2019?
What Im doing wrong here?

My original files date format comes like '17/09/2019' format. When reading date column should I define what date format it is?

Comment: Pass the argument `dayfirst = True` into `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `to_datetime` line adding the `dayfirst`

```
data['Dip Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Dip Time'],dayfirst=True)
```